# Rename a launch command in cmd prompt on windows

Tags: windows, cmd, shortcut, prompt

I'm looking for a way to launch an executable file, say chrome.exe, by passing a shorthand lettering to the command prompt to launch it. So for example, chrome in my mind is Google Chrome and to launch it i'd like to be able to type 'gc' into command prompt and for command prompt to know I want to launch chrome.exe.  Is it possible to do something like this? To have some sort of renaming for application.exe's or to create a shortcut board somewhere that cmd would know what it is i'm looking for?

Comment: Write a tiny application called *gc.exe* that launches Google Chrome, and append its location to the `PATH` environment variable. Other than that, you could probably create a soft link to your app in a directory that is in your search path.

Comment: an `.exe` is kind of overkill for this task. A simple `.bat` should do fine. Also `doskey gc="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` is a possibilty.

Comment: put an edit in my answer, ended up doing exactly what IInspectable wrote to do

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was mentioning my idea to another techy mate of a mate who knew exactly what I was asking for and told me to do what IInspectable recommended. So my steps were as follows

1) create a .BAT file called gc.bat and store it in a folder in my C drive called "My_Commands"
2) I then proceeded to add this to the PATH env variable (start menu -> r.click computer -> properties -> advanced settings > environment variables -> lower half find PATH -> edit -> add file path in there)

3) now when i create a command and store it in my_commands folder it will be automatically added to the path environment variable and my shortcuts will work right away.

4) now what i do to launch something is windows key plus the letters of whatever command i made. so I made gc command which launches Google Chrome and now I will make other commands to launch other things, I think I will make more complicated commands as well, bats to launch chrome to certain webpages with url provided like stack overflow maybe ;)